# sorting python dictionary with more than one values

Tags: python, dictionary

I have created a dictionary like this:

```
Dict={'h1':[('h2',3.5), ('h3',2.5), ('h4', 1.5)], 'h2':[('h1',2.4), ('h4', 5.3), ('h3',1.1)], 'h3':[('h4',4.2),('h2',7.3),('h1',2.1)], 'h4':[('h1',4.3),('h3',3.2),('h2',4.3)]}
```

I want to sort the values in h1, h2, h3 and h4 by values.

example:

```
'h1':[('h4', 1.5), ('h3',2.5), ('h2',3.5)]
```

and so on for h2, h3 and h4.

Comment: You should not come asking for a solution but for help. What have you tried so far. Which exactly problem you are facing off?

Comment: I have tried to use sorted like this  
sorted(Dict.keys(), key=lambda k:horse[k][1], reverse=True)
However, i get keys in sorted order ['h2', 'h4', 'h1', 'h3'] which is not what i want. I am not sure how to pas the values to sort .

Comment: You can't sort a dictionary, by definition.  Maybe you need this?  https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

Comment: In case you need a sorted dictionary you may want to take a look at [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

Comment: @user5981666 Do you want to sort every list in the dictionary by the second value of the tuples in the lists? If that's the case, you could edit your question to reflect this. "Sort by value" can mean different things when you're working with tuples in lists in dictionaries that contain both strings and floats.

Comment: Yes you are right. It does sound confusing.  My bad.
I managed to do it by creating a single list and sorting it by value then created a dictionary like I needed. 
list=[(h1,h2,3.5),(h1,h4,1.5),(h1,h3,2.5), (h2, h1,2.4)....and so on]
sorted by value then created a dictionary like I wanted from the sorted list
'h1':[('h4', 1.5), ('h3',2.5), ('h2',3.5)] 
It worked but I was looking for a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of *"(...) sort the values in h1, h2, h3 and h4 by values"* is ambiguous but judging from OP's example output, I think he/she wants to sort every list in the dictionary by the second element in the tuples (the floats). That's what this dictionary comprehension does:

```
Dict={'h1':[('h2',3.5), ('h3',2.5), ('h4', 1.5)], 'h2':[('h1',2.4), ('h4', 5.3), ('h3',1.1)], 'h3':[('h4',4.2),('h2',7.3),('h1',2.1)], 'h4':[('h1',4.3),('h3',3.2),('h2',4.3)]}

{k:sorted(Dict[k], key=lambda x : x[1]) for k in Dict}
```

Example:

```
>>> Dict={'h1':[('h2',3.5), ('h3',2.5), ('h4', 1.5)], 'h2':[('h1',2.4), ('h4', 5.3), ('h3',1.1)], 'h3':[('h4',4.2),('h2',7.3),('h1',2.1)], 'h4':[('h1',4.3),('h3',3.2),('h2',4.3)]}
>>> 
>>> Dict_sorted = {k:sorted(Dict[k], key=lambda x : x[1]) for k in Dict}
>>> 
>>> for elem in sorted(Dict_sorted):
...     print elem, Dict_sorted[elem]
... 
h1 [('h4', 1.5), ('h3', 2.5), ('h2', 3.5)]
h2 [('h3', 1.1), ('h1', 2.4), ('h4', 5.3)]
h3 [('h1', 2.1), ('h4', 4.2), ('h2', 7.3)]
h4 [('h3', 3.2), ('h1', 4.3), ('h2', 4.3)]
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is much better than what i was doing.

Answer (score 0):

Using for loop and `itemgetter`:

```
from operator import itemgetter
for key, items in Dict.iteritems():
   Dict[key] = sorted(items, key=itemgetter(1))
```